# How to locally cancel a Push Notification in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate

is there a way to stop a push notification from happening in Swift? I am trying to create notification settings and store that info in UserDefaults, then using that data decide which push notifications to cancel in a `AppDelegate` delegate method. Is this possible? or will this have to be implemented on the server side?

Comment: even i want to do this, can you share your solution. Please

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid registering to push notifications altogether on app launch.

You can also update the server to avoid sending specific notifications and avoid them presenting for the user on their phone.

Your third option is to write a [notification service extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension)
And use some kind of shared persistent store between the extension and the app to prevent certain notifications from being shown to the user (even when the application is terminated).

The options you suggested are a bit problematic if the application is in background or terminated state as you have no control on push that is presented to the user. When in the foreground you can use `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate) and prevent notifications from being shown to the user by conforming to the

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, 
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification, 
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
```

And call the completion with `completionHandler(.none)`

**EDIT**, as pointed out by @Rob, on iOS 11 direct filtering was not supported for the `UNNotificationServiceExtension`.
But since iOS 13.3, an entitlement that does supports filtering was introduced in the form `com.apple.developer.usernotifications.filtering` [see](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_usernotifications_filtering) for more information and example.
TLDR; on `didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void)` when you want to suppress the notification just call the contentHandler as follow `contentHandler(UNNotificationContent())`

Related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43499834/is-it-possible-to-prevent-a-remote-notification-from-being-displayed)

Comment: I’ve always done it server-side. As I read the notification service extension, you can change or supplement the alert message, but not suppress it. E.g., “You may also modify the alert text as long as you don’t remove it. If the content object doesn’t contain any alert text, the system ignores your modifications and delivers the original notification content.” I’m not aware of a mechanism to suppress the alert. When you say you can “prevent certain notifications from behind shown”, precisely how are you doing that?

Comment: Hey Rob - great point, see my edit to the post, thank you for pointing it out. Please see - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_usernotifications_filtering on how to filter notifications using a specific entitelment